# Proxmox Server Connectivity Issues: Duplicate Hostnames and IP Addresses

Tags: linux, router, hostname, proxmox

It appears that I'm encountering an issue with my recently established Proxmox servers. My configuration involves two servers: a *Dell Poweredge T310* and a *Dell Poweredge T330*.

#### 1 and a half year ago

I purchased a *Dell PowerEdge T310* and a *Dell PowerEdge T330*. Initially, I only required one, so I set up the T310 for some personal activities with a friend, which were primarily gaming-oriented. Thus, I named it **POZIEL-SERVER**. Given our modest requirements, a straightforward Ubuntu installation was sufficient.

#### Last month

Having recently relocated, I availed myself of a new internet provider and upgraded to a new router. With this fresh start, I opted to install Proxmox on both of my servers, a recommendation from a colleague. Initially, this colleague assisted with the setup, which was executed successfully. We even managed to connect the servers in a cluster, simplifying my access to a single web interface.

#### Yesterday

Yesterday, I opted to reset my servers due to an unsuitable hostname, which was challenging to alter from Proxmox. As my hosting requirements were minimal, the reinstallation process was swift. I reconfigured both servers with Proxmox, assigning the hostname **HATENSHI** and static IP `192.168.2.100` to my *T330* and the hostname **KENTOGE** with static IP `192.168.2.101` to my *T310*. Initially, everything functioned correctly until this morning when I attempted to access the Proxmox web GUI. I discovered that **KENTOGE** was incessantly connecting and disconnecting from the cluster. To investigate the issue, I accessed my router's admin panel to review the connected devices. As evidenced by the screenshot, both servers appear twice with the same static IP, distinguished only by different MAC addresses.

**IMAGE:** [My router configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COyVK.png)

Being relatively new to server management and homelab setups, I'm encountering some challenges. Not only am I having difficulties with Proxmox, but my hostnames aren't being resolved by the router and appear to be duplicating.

Thank you for your assistance. I apologize for the lengthy context; I aimed to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: What's in your host's logs? Also, drop the router-gui. Those things usually show just DHCP-clients or (sometimes) MACs (as long as TTL), which is usually unreliable. But whatever you do, check the logs of your hosts.

Comment: I forgot to adjust my original post after receiving no returns; I decided to factory reset both my server and router. Since then, I've encountered no other issues, except my router's inability to resolve my server's hostname. However, something you mentioned piques my interest - "drop the router-gui". While I'm not operating in a corporate setting, but rather for enjoyment in my home lab. My router/modem is provided by my internet service provider, but it seems you're suggesting there might be another way to manage it other than the GUI? Thank you kindly for your help.